# Number of rows per "percentile"

Tags: sql, postgresql, percentile

I would like a Postgres query returning the number of rows per percentile.

**Input:**

| id | name | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | apple | 12 |
| 2 | banana | 6 |
| 3 | orange | 18 |
| 4 | pineapple | 26 |
| 4 | lemon | 30 |

**Desired output:**

| percentile_3_1 | percentile_3_2 | percentile_3_3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2 |

`percentile_3_1` = number of fruits in the 1st `3-precentile` (i.e. with a price < 10)

Comment: `count(*) FILTER (WHERE ntile(3) = 1)`? Not sure if there's a more efficient way

Comment: @Bergi: I think the term "percentile" is misleading here.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Oh right, the number of rows per 3-percentile is just `count(*)/3`, which is not really helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postgres has the [window function `ntile()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html#FUNCTIONS-WINDOW-TABLE) and a number of very useful [ordered-set aggregate functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-ORDEREDSET-TABLE) for percentiles. But you seem to have the wrong term.

> number of fruits in the 1st 3-precentile (i.e. with a price < 10)

That's not a "percentile". That's the count of rows with a price below a third of the maximum.

Assuming `price` is defined `numeric NOT NULL CHECK (price > 0)`, here is a generalized query to get row counts for any given number of partitions:

```sql
WITH bounds AS (
   SELECT *
   FROM  (
      SELECT bound AS lo, lead(bound) OVER (ORDER BY bound) AS hi
      FROM  (
         SELECT generate_series(0, x, x/3) AS bound  -- number of partitions here!
         FROM  (SELECT max(price) AS x FROM tbl) x
         ) sub1
      ) sub2
   WHERE  hi IS NOT NULL
   )
SELECT b.hi, count(t.price)
FROM   bounds   b
LEFT   JOIN tbl t ON t.price > b.lo AND t.price <= b.hi
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1;
```

Result:

```
                  hi | count
 --------------------+------
 10.0000000000000000 |     1
 20.0000000000000000 |     2
 30.0000000000000000 |     2
```

Notably, each partition *includes* the upper bound, as this makes more sense while deriving partitions from the maximum value. So your quote would read:

> i.e. with a price <= 10

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_15&fiddle=633256013ded1b9000572f5d2e5348a5)*